# (Javascript) I don't understand how the counter and result variables interact with each other

Tags: javascript, counter

```
let result = 1;  
for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1)   
{  
  result = result * 2;  
}  
console.log(result);
```

So this code finds the 10th power of 2, or 2^10, and it works fine. I just don't understand HOW it works, specifically how the result and counter variable interact with each other. If I remove the for statement the answer comes out to 2 which makes sense. But when I add the for statement back in it comes out to 1024, and this doesn't make sense to me because I don't understand how the counter and result interact with each other. Sorry if I sound redundant, I'm a noob and have no idea what I'm talking about.

EDIT: I understand now, thanks

Comment: There's no interaction. `result = result * 2` is just repeated 10 times.

Comment: Add `console.log(result);` after `result = result * 2;` and you will know why.

Comment: counter and result variables don't directly interact with each other.  `counter` simple runs 10 times in the for loop, and the result variable is multiplied to 2 10 times, because it is inside the loop.

Comment: I think what you want to ask is `What does loop do` and specifically for your question [How does "for" loop work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: The `counter` variable controls the number of iterations of the `for` loop. In other words, it controls how many times the code inside the `for` loop block runs. So it is not related to `result`, but determines how many times the line `result = result * 2` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Let try and understand your code.

```
let result = 1;
```

In above statement you declare a variable and initialize it to 1

```
for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1)   
{  
  result = result * 2;  
}
```

The above is a for loop. What is a for loop.

> A for loop is an iteration that repeats until a specified condition
>   evaluates to false.

Below is the syntax of a for loop

```
for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression])
{
   statement(s)
}
```

So in your case the loop will keep executing the statements until the condition evaluates to false. Which in your case is `counter < 10` that means as soon as the counter becomes 10 the condition evaluates to false. But till it becomes 10 it keeps executing the below statement.

```
result = result * 2;
```

The below statement logs the value of result when the loop has finished executing.

```
console.log(result); // 1024
```

So `result` and `counter` don't interact with each other. `Counter` helps decides the number of iterations/cycles of the for loop. And the result is incremented because of the statements being executed inside the loop.

Hope this helps :)

For more please refer [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)